# "this" is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, object, this

I am writing a JavaScript program that runs an object's method every second. The method just logs the object's property "x", and then adds one to it.

The class from which the object (called "player") is constructed is called "Snake", and the property "x" is clearly defined as 0. However, when put through my "everyTick" function, it logs 'undefined'.

This is very strange because the method also logs player.x, which does exactly what it should. But when I use "this" instead of "player", it logs undefined. Can anyone explain why and how to fix it?

Here's the code.

```
var FPS = 1;
var toBeRun = {
  func: function() {},
  index: 0
};

function tickFunction(func) {
  this.func = function() {
    func();
  }
}

function everyTick() {
  toBeRun.func()
  setTimeout(function() {everyTick();}, 1000 / FPS);
}

function forever(func) {
  toBeRun = new tickFunction(func);
}


function Snake() {
  this.x = 0;

  this.say = function() {
    console.log(player.x);
    console.log(this.x);

    player.x++;
    this.x++;
  }
}


var player = new Snake();

function start() {
  forever(player.say);
}

everyTick();
```

It's really confusing when you just see it like that, so here it is in CodePen:
http://codepen.io/Plygon/pen/jqJZvq?editors=0011

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because, when you call `forever`, you are passing a reference to the `player.say` function, but that reference is not bound to the `Snake` object. So when the function is called, it doesn't know what `this` is.

Here's a simple example:

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.say = function () {
        return this.name;
    };
}

var p = new Person('Bob');
console.log(p.say()); // Bob
var fn = p.say;
console.log(p.say()); // undefined;
```

What you need to do is bind the function to the object. The function's `bind` method returns a new function where `this` is bound to whatever object you pass to `bind`:

```
var boundFn = p.say.bind(p);
console.log(boundFn()); // Bob
```

So, if you do:

```
forever(player.say.bind(player));
```

You should be able to use `this` as you expect to within the `say` function.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the `scope` of `this` try this:

```
function Snake() {
  this.x = 0;
  var parent =  this;

  this.say = function() {
    console.log(player.x);
    console.log(parent.x);

    player.x++;
    parent.x++;
  }
}
```

Here `this` inside `this.say` has a local scope for say function, you need to refer to `this` from the `parent` function.

Comment: My class period just ended, so I can't verify your answer right now, but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
function start() {
  forever(player.say);
}
```

When you send the `player.say` function to be used in cycle, you lost the connection with the `player` object.

Then in the place when the funcion is called, you make a simple **function invocation**, but not a **method on the player object**:

```
function tickFunction(func) {
  this.func = function() {
    func(); // simple function invocation, which has `this` as `undefined`
  }
}
```

To solve the problem, just update the `start` function to this one:

```
function start() {
  forever(player.say.bind(player));
}
```

The `bind()` will create a new function with the context always connected with the `player` instance when calling it.

[This article](http://rainsoft.io/gentle-explanation-of-this-in-javascript/) gives a lot of details about `this` keyword in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your function loses its context (the "this").

First option is to save the "this" (var self = this).

Another option is to use bind, call or apply

Hope this helps :)